# cambiar un display none a block con js?

Tags: javascript

Me gustaría mostrar una leyenda después de que mi mouse detecte el evento, mi problema es que logro capturar el evento pero no puedo hacer que mi leyenda salga.
Mi código sería el siguiente:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",(e) =>{

mostrarHover('.propiedades','.leyenda-hover');

 


});


  const $d = document;
 function mostrarHover(propiedades,hover){
  $d.addEventListener('mouseover',(e) =>{
    if(e.target.matches(propiedades)){
      for(let i= 0; i<propiedades.lenght;i++){
       
          $d.propiedades[i].querySelectorAll(hover).style.display='block'
       
      }
     console.log(e)
      
    }

  })

 
}
```

```css
.middle{
    display: flex;
}


.leyenda-hover{
    display: none;
    border:none;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 45px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 40px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: auto;

}

 

.propiedades{
    margin: 0 10px;
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px ;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:40px ;

}
.propiedades:hover{
 background-color: #fdefef;
}
```

```html
      <!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/1bbadd233d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
   
  
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 
   
      <div class="middle">
        <div class="home">
          <i class="fas propiedades fa-home"></i>
          <span class="leyenda-hover">Inicio</span>
        </div>
        <div class="user">
          <i class="fas propiedades  fa-user-friends"></i>
          <span class="leyenda-hover">Amigos</span>
        </div>
        <div class="play">
           <i class="far propiedades fa-play-circle"></i>
           <span class="leyenda-hover">Videos</span>
          </div>
        <div class="users">
          <i class="fas propiedades fa-users"></i>
          <span class="leyenda-hover">Grupos</span>
        </div>
        <div class="barras">
          <i class="fas propiedades   fa-bars"></i>
         
        </div>
      </div>
 





        
        
</body>

</html>
```

Lo que he realizado es que cargue los valores en el DOMcontent y les mandé a mi función el parametro, entonces como son varios elementos a los que quiero aplicarles  el display block para que se vea, entonces usé un for para recorrerlos y aquí es donde no puedo hacer que se vean mis leyendas,la verdad soy inexperto y me gustaría aprender de ustedes.

Comment: Si el elemento al que quieres afectar es `$d`, entonces solo necesitas hacer esto: `$d.style.display = "block"`. Tendrías que explicar qué contiene `propiedades` para entender el contexto de ese bloque de código.

Comment: Hola buenas noches gracias por tu respuesta.  Mira quiero hacer lo siguiente: propiedades tiene una caja con icono  al momento de pasar el mouse  debería mostrar conmo un hover una caja o leyenda  que al momento de quitar el mouse se quite la leyenda, entonces logro detectar todos los eventos ´pero no me despliega nada.  la variable $d  es solo una breviación de document.

Comment: Déjame ver si entendí bien. Me dices que `propiedades` contiene un elemento del documento (una caja) el cual contiene a otro elemento (un ícono), y lo que quieres es que, al momento de colocar el cursor del *mouse* sobre la caja se muestre un cuadro de texto a manera de leyenda. ¿Es así? En ese caso, tienes que asociar el elemento al cual quieres afectar con esa funcionalidad con los eventos `mouseover`  y `mouseout`.

Comment: Cuando se ejecute `mouseover`, muestras la leyenda. Suponiendo que se trata de un elemento, solo tienes que hacer `elementoLeyenda.style.display = "block"`. Y cuando se produzca el evento `mouseout`, ocultas la leyenda `elementoLeyenda.style.display = "none"`.

Comment: Exacto eso mismo quiero hacer, y ya estan asociados incluso puedo ver los eventos en consola cuando los estoy detectando.  mi problema es que  la variable hover  que en mi caso es la leyenda no le puedo aplicar el display block para que se vea.

Comment: Si entiendo lo que me comenta de aplicarle al elemento leyenda, en mi caso son 6  por que es un menu, por eso lo recorrí con el el for y quedo como propiedades[i]  y en este momento lo tengo de la siguiente manera

Comment: Lo que muestras en la publicación: `$d.propiedades[i].style.display='block'`, solo indica que, en el documento, aplicas el `display: block` a distintos elementos que contiene `propiedades`. Creo que será mejor que edites tu publicación y añadas la porción de código HTML asociada a esa parte, y un ejemplo en código JavaScript de la llamada a la función `mostrarHover`.

Comment: for(let i= 0; i<propiedades.lenght;i++){
       
          $d.propiedades[i].querySelectorAll(hover).style.display='block'
       
      }

Comment: ok trataré de subir un ejemplo muchas gracias amigo.

Comment: Listo envie mi pedazo de código haber si podrías ayudarme y mil gracias

Answer (score 1):

No es necesario el bucle. Basta con que asocies los eventos `mouseover` y `mouseout` al menú de opciones, y verifiques si el elemento que directamente está siendo afectado por esos eventos contiene la clase `propiedades`. De ser así, puedes acceder a su respectiva leyenda a través de la propiedad `nextElementSibling` con la cual puedes tomar el elemento que sigue a la opción (que, en este caso, es la leyenda), y, finalmente, aplicas el `display: block` y `display: none` para cada caso.

```
function mostrarHover(propiedades, hover){
    let menu = document.querySelector("div.middle");
    
    menu.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
        if (e.target.classList.contains("propiedades")){
            e.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
        }
    }, false);
  
    menu.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
        if (e.target.classList.contains("propiedades")){
            e.target.nextElementSibling.style.display = "none";
        }
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: Epale! muchisimas gracias tu código funciona a la perfeccion .  Dios te bendiga.

Comment: De nada. Un saludo.

Comment: Solo como comentario, dado que el elemento `<i>` es uno *en línea* (*inline*), en lugar de `block` tiene que ir `inline`, aunque ya no se mostraría por debajo de la opción asociada, sino a la derecha de esta.

Comment: Tampoco es necesaria la función `mostrarHover`. Todo eso lo puedes colocar por fuera y seguirá funcionando.

Comment: Gracias Alexis lo tomaré en cuenta, la verdad soy novato con ganas de aprender . de hecho quise hacerlo con  hover desde css pero no sé por que no me dejaba por eso  obté por hacerlo en js, de cualquier forma gracias a ti se solucionó.